# SQL select query to find a record at a specific record count

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

```
Table: MyData
============================
id | Name | Surname
----------------------------
1  | AB   | ABAB
2  | CD   | CDCD
3  | EF   | EFEF
4  | CD   | CDCD
5  | CD   | CDCD
6  | AB   | ABAB
7  | CD   | CDCD 
8  | CD   | CDCD
```

Select the `id` for the record for a specific name for the given count so i.e.: First I get the distinct names

```
AB
CD
EF
```

Then I would like to get the `ID` for the 3 occurrence of each account so starting with AB

```
For name AB
Start with id = 1
eg: SELECT id FROM MyData WHERE id >= 1 Name = 'AB' and count <= 3 --Should return id=6 as there are only 2 occurrences so it should just return the last one

For name CD
Start with id = 1
eg: SELECT id FROM MyData WHERE id >= 1 Name = 'CD' and count <= 3 --Should return id=5 as record 5 contains the 3 occurrence
Set id = returned id + 1 so start id = 6
eg: SELECT id FROM MyData WHERE id >= 6 Name = 'CD' and count <= 3 --Should return id=8 as from id 6 the last occurrence is at id 8

For name EF
Start with id = 1
eg: SELECT id FROM MyData WHERE id >= 1 Name = 'EF' and count <= 3 --Should return id=3
```

I'm struggling to find a clean way to accomplish this with ms sql. Any help appreciated

Comment: Take a look at the [ROW_NUMBER() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For name AB
Start with id = 1
eg: SELECT id FROM MyData WHERE id >= 1 Name = 'AB' and count <= 3
```

Try the below query and make changes accordingly -

```
select top 1 id from (SELECT top 3 id FROM PPBSample WHERE id >= 1 and Name = 'AB' order by id ) as test order by id desc
```

**Note** - Within the above query change `id >= your number` and `Name` accordingly, as per your requirement.

Comment: Could you perhaps tell me how you would implement this sql using hibernate